# How do you express a int[] property in interface description language?

Tags: c#, com, idl

How would you implement this property in IDL:

```
    public int[] Params
    {
        get
        {
            return _Params;
        }
        set
        {
            _Params = value;
        }
    }
```

I tried the idl code below

```
[propget, helpstring("The click through parameters")] 
    HRESULT Params([out, retval] int *rVal);
[propput, helpstring("The click through parameters")] 
    HRESULT Params([in] int *RnewVal);
```

But my compiler is looking for this

```
public int get_Params()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void set_Params(ref int rVal)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I'm 99.999% sure it's a problem with the types.

Comment: You misspelled Params in the original code.

Comment: touche I did. Fixed. That mistake wasn't in the code, however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM typelib importer prefers to deal with Automation-compliant interfaces, so use `SAFEARRAY`:

```
[propget, helpstring("The click through parameters")] 
HRESULT Params([out, retval] SAFEARRAY(long) *rVal);

[propput, helpstring("The click through parameters")] 
HRESULT Params([in] SAFEARRAY(long) RnewVal);
```